# Remote Desktop doesn't maximize to fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, fullscreen

I have a problem with Remote Desktop connection in Windows 7. When I connect to remote computer I would like to switch to fullscreen like I did in previous versions - just by clicking maximize. When I was in fullscreen mode and I moved the mouse to the upper border of the screen, a nice bar appeared and I could minimize RDP or close it.

In Windows 7 when I click on the maximize button the window maximizes like a normal window - menu start/taskbar (whatever you call it) is still visible and because the resolution of the RDP client desktop is set like on the computer that I'm using it's not fully visible and scrollbars appear. That's really annoying.

Can anyone tell me what to do? Is it a bug or maybe there is a "magic shortcut" that is poorly documented and does the trick? (I was trying to find it myself first of course, but no result)

Comment: What do you have listed for your settings under the Display tab in the RDP client screen?  Is it set all the way to the right?  I can RDP to my 1680x1050 session with a 1280x1024 monitor without scrollbars in fullscreen.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> - which switches the client between full-screen mode and window mode.
That should put you back in full screen mode.
In case the <kbd>BREAK</kbd> key isn't available, try one of these key combinations:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PAUSE</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PRTSCN</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>SCRLK</kbd>

Reference: [Remote Desktop Services Shortcut Keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-shortcut-keys)

Comment: What a weird (moronic) shortcut :O

Comment: Plus, I don't have a break key on my laptop.

Comment: @Manu The key is Pause/Break. I'm sure that you have the key, you just might have to use a function key to access it.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok I thought so too, but I think they just removed it from the keyboard (dell inspiron 15). See http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/dell/cnet_inspiron15_rev3521_gallery_14_800.jpg

Comment: @Manu I can't believe Dell would leave you with no alternative. That's just dumb. It looks like most people had to resort to registry tweaks to map the Pause/Break key to something, use an external keyboard, or use the on-screen keyboard. It's absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: @Manu Try Ctrl+Fn+Alt+Insert

Answer (score 10):

When you launch RDP dialog and before you logon/connect to the remote computer, select the Display Tab and set your display configuration. If you want full screen mode, set the slider all the way to the right.

Comment: That works, but when I minimize I can't return to fullscreen is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Strange, when you minimize that shouldn't happen. Try restarting the remote session.

Comment: Try clicking the "Restore down" button and then "Maximize" again, that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue with systems running Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2 whose resolution is set at 1366×768. Microsoft has created a hotfix which you can read about / request here:

[Remote desktop is not displayed in Full-Screen mode when the screen resolution is 1366× 768 pixels in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2582172)

If you're lazy or don't want to give MS your email, you can just download it from [here](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix377500/7600/free/435474_intl_x64_zip.exe). Just know that by doing so Microsoft will have no way of notifying you if there is a recall on the fix.

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to question [Remote Desktop won't maximize](https://superuser.com/questions/19661/remote-desktop-wont-maximize)--which offers helpful images of how to configure your RDP session prior to logging in.

Also, Craig's suggestion of pressing ctrl-alt-break works well if your session fails to maximize when logging in or if it randomly jumps out of full-screen mode while in a session.

Finally, if you happen to prefer having the RDP title bar visible at the top of the screen during full-screen mode, but without the annoyance of scrollbars to the right and bottom of your screen, open your saved .rdp session file in a text editor and edit the following lines:

```
screen mode id:i:1
desktopwidth:i:<set to screen width>
desktopheight:i:<set to screen height>
```

Consider adjusting desktopheight:i to a lower number than the screen height if you prefer to keep the taskbar of your local computer visible beneath the RDP window.

Answer (score 2):

If you have win 7 SP1 it high recommended to update to new rdp client 8.1 :

[Update for RDP 8.1 is available for Windows 7 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2923545)

It go to full screen automatically, or by right click in title bar.
[image: new rdp client]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar problem. I am using Windows 10 and RDPing into a Linux box. Setting my RDP to full screen mode and having the session maximized did not prevent horizontal and vertical scroll bars from appearing. *To get rid of these bars*, I saved my RDP connection settings by pressing `Save As...` on the first tab of the configuration. Then, I opened the saved `*.rdp` file in a text editor (Notepad or Wordpad will work.) I then added this line to the top of the file, saved it and used this .rdp file to successfully log in without scroll bars:

```
smart sizing:i:1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am Using Dell Latitude E5450 Laptop with windows 7.
Ctrl + Alt + Fn + B worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen users not being able to maximize because of the Screen setting "Use multiple monitors for this connection" - when this is checked, the Full screen slider remains locked.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser - as this is not an answer, please post it as a comment as opposed to an answer.  This will allow actual answers to be separated from commentary posts and help answers get found easier.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in, in the dialog box where you put your username and password, there is a little drop down arrow in the bottom left for "Show options". 
Under the display tab, first try full screen under Display Configuration. If that doesn't work, ***change it to the resolution of your screen*** -- mine is 1920x1080. This will allow you to go full screen.

I run 4 monitors, all of which are different. This confuses the RDM. Just change the resolution to your screen's maximum resolution and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to get it to fit nicely in a portion of my super ultrawide display (32:9 DQHD). I was hoping to have it take the center of the screen without having scroll bars and still with the ability to see my other windows.

The solution for me was:
[image: RDP Menu -> Smart Sizing On]

`Right Click RDP Menu Bar` `->` `Smart sizing` `=` `On`

That made it so that it only took the space that was available and hide the scroll bars, although it did squash the content a bit since the display size still didn't match the space on my display (Lame). It'd be better if I could just hide the Menu Bar.

Answer (score -1):

Though this thread is for RDP, I faced similar issue in RDCMan so sharing it FYI. I resolved it by unckecking "Lock Window Size" in View...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Could also include a screenshot on where to locate this option?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by going to the icons on my local toolbar and unpinning the most recent ones from my toolbar.  Immediately, upon unpinning a password manager, my remote toolbar appeared.

Comment: Thank you for trying to be helpful. However, your explanation indicates your problem was different than the one OP was trying to solve.